# Seemingly circular dependencies causing issues with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a IUserService (and other services) that I am registering in bulk in my ServiceInstaller.cs:

```
  container.Register(
                AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>()
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Singleton)
                );
```

I then I have IAuthenticationService which I register as in my generic WindsorInstaller.cs file:

```
  container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IAuthenticationService))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(AuthenticationService)));
```

Now things were working just fine until I added a public property for `IAuthenticationService` in my UserService.

It seems there is a circular dependacy or some timing issue of when things get registered, as I am getting the error:

```
Can't create component 'ABCD.Services.UserService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
ABCD.Services.UserService is waiting for the following dependencies:

Services:
- ABCD.Services.Interfaces.IAuthenticationService which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.

ABCD.Services.AuthenticationService is waiting for the following dependencies:

Services:
- ABCD.Services.Interfaces.IUserService which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
```

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: Circular dependencies can be solved by using property injection.

Comment: So if it is constructor injection it won't work but with property it will? why is that?

Comment: To construct `UserService` you have to call its constructor.  To do that you have to have an `AuthenticationService`, which requires a `UserService` passed in the constructor, which requires an `AuthenticationService`, which requires...

Comment: "How can I solve this issue?" -> by not having cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Get rid of your circular dependencies (this is the preferred option), or
2. Work around them, by using property injection, rather than constructor injection.

Using property injection (as illustrated in [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715702/seemingly-circular-dependencies-causing-issues-with-castle-windsor/7719611#7719611)) allows you to create instances of your classes without providing all the dependencies at the time of creation. The downside is that it is not as obvious to users of the class what they need to do to instantiate and fully configure the instance.

For a nice explanation of how to refactor to remove a ciruclar dependency see this blog post by Miško Hevery:

- [Circular Dependency in constructors and Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)

Comment: Property injection worked for me. However, I needed to get rid of constructors completely and move those classes to property injection completely.

Answer (score 4):

Property injection will solve your problem, because it breaks the dependency cycle. Just look at Krzysztof's example and try to instantiate a `UserService`; You can't. Now take a look at the following example:

```
public class UserService
{
    UserService(AuthenticationService a) { }
}

public class AuthenticationService 
{
    AuthenticationService() { }

    public UserService UserService { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, the `UserService` dependency of the `AuthenticationService` is 'promoted' from a constructor argument to a property. Now you can create a user service like this:

```
var a = new AuthenticationService();
var s = new UserService(a);
a.UserService = s;
```

Breaking the circular dependency can be done with property injection and any dependency injection framework can be configured to allow property injection.

Comment: +1 This is the immediate solution. However, it's worth pointing out that a circular dependency is often an indication of a design flaw. A better solution is to perform root cause analysis to completely remove the circular dependency

Comment: Furthermore, I'd like to point out that from an API design point of view, Constructor Injection and Property Injection aren't equivalent, since they imply different guarantees about the invariants of the class.

Comment: I completely agree with Mark on this.

Answer (score 2):

here's your scenario as I understand it:

```
public class UserService
{
   UserService(AuthenticationService a){}
}

public class AuthenticationService 
{
   AuthenticationService (UserService a){}
}
```

How would you create instances of both classes, creating at most single instance of each class?