# Dependency Injection linking two objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Now at creation of the `Engine`, it requires a new `Compoment`, and the `Engine` pass 'this' itself to the `Component`.

At the creation of the `Component`, it needs to know its parent `Engine` and integrates with it by calling its `IntegrateComponent()` function.

It is kind of a circular referencing situation here. How do I do this in DI? (Castle Windsor in my case)

```
public class Engine : IEngine {
  private IComponent _someComponent;
  public Engine() {
    _component = new Component(this);
  }
  public void IntegrateComponent() {
    //init component...
  }
}

public class Component : IComponent {
  private readonly IEngine _engine;
  public Component(IEngine engine) {
    _engine = engine;
    _engine.IntegrateComponent();
  }
}

static void Main() {
  var engine = new Engine();
}
```

EDIT ----------------------------------------

I want something like ...

```
Register<IComponent>().ImplementedBy<Component>(); 
Register<IEngine>().ImplementedBy<Engine>(); 
---> Resolve<IEngine>(); ...
```

But how am I going to tell the DI this engine & this component reference to each other?

Comment: Where do you need DI? (Can you show an example of what you're trying to do?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to design in such a way that there are no cyclic references.If not, using property injection, you can break this

```
var engine = new Engine();
engine.Component = new Component(engine);
```

This is based on Mark Seemann's excellent book - Dependency Injection in .Net.

There is already a thread on this: [Seemingly circular dependencies causing issues with Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715702/seemingly-circular-dependencies-causing-issues-with-castle-windsor)

Comment: I don't prefer property injection here because it exposes the internal references to public. I accept your answer because a post from your link answered my question. Thanks.