# IOC Graph Cycle Detection with Windsor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I was working on a very large program that has over 100 items in an IOC container (we use Castle Windsor for the container). I mistakenly created a cycle in the graph for the container. I fixed the problem and now I am attempting to create a unit test so that this issue will get detected in the future. I settled on using a depth first search across the graph to find cycles. The simplified program below creates the same problem:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class3 Object3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Class2
{
    public Class1 Object1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Class3
{
    public Class2 Object2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<Class1>().ImplementedBy<Class1>(),
        Component.For<Class2>().ImplementedBy<Class2>(),
        Component.For<Class3>().ImplementedBy<Class3>());

    var object1 = container.Resolve<Class1>();

    Debug.Assert(object1.Object3 != null);
    Debug.Assert(object1.Object3.Object2 != null);
    Debug.Assert(object1.Object3.Object2.Object1 != null);//fail
}
```

I figured that this is a common problem. However, after doing a few hours of research I did not find that Windsor or anyone else who had this problem or any code that would detect this problem. I strongly suspect that someone already created a solution to this problem that is specific to Windsor in a library or Windsor does have detection for this problem and I have not found it yet. My question is where is the code that solves this problem? I find it hard to believe that I am the only person who had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7715702/1698557) and its answers.  Because you're using property injection, cycles are perfectly fine because they're just setup after all the objects are created.  If you used constructor injection (which you definitely should be using), then you'd get a run-time exception any time a cycle is detected, and it would contain all the details you need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it did shed some light on how other people tackle this problem. In that link Mark Seemann stated that circular references are usually a sign of a design flaw and I tend to agree since it could cause infinite loops if not managed correctly. I would also like the avoid run time errors since this kind of problem can be detected in a unit test. But thanks again for advice.